# Commenting Under 50 Reputation

Tags: discussion, comments, reputation, not-an-answer

I'm a new user, and I have less than 50 Reputation. I want to comment on a question, but I can't, because I don't have 50+ reputation. What should I do? Should I post it as an answer?

Comment: Good on you for asking before doing it. But no, you shouldn't. Comment boxes are for comments, and answer boxes, for answers. Either gain the rep then come back once at 50, or give up on that question until it's clearer, without you needing to comment. In the meantime, suggesting edits is a good way to quickly get to 50. Just remember, if you decide to take that path, to edit all of the opportunities within a post at once :). Good luck!

Comment: See [this MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147529/how-can-i-ask-for-clarification-on-a-question-id-like-to-answer-if-i-cant-add). It should answer your question.

Comment: The canonical is *[Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173)* (cross-site).

Answer (score 3):

No you really shouldn't. If you have something to add, do it as an answer.
It is against the rules to comment in answer!

I've made this mistake before!

Comment: You also should not post answers for questions that are well known to be duplicates...

Comment: Its easy to make mistakes on this site,  people come here eager to get questions answered or to share their knowledge with the world. The site has blocks and opens up features to you in slow progression for a very good reason, that eagerness needs to be tempered a little first :)